# Multiplicity of roots of a fewnomial

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, fewnomial

It is easy to show that a complex polynomial with $N$ non-zero coefficients cannot have a non-zero root of multiplicity $N$ or more. Is there any standard name / reference for this fact?

Also, observing that $(x+a)^{N-1}$ has $N$ non-zero coefficients and a root of multiplicity $N-1$, can the assertion above be strengthened given that the polynomial in question is not of this form?

---

<sub>The small print: posting on behalf of a friend; also posted at [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2555167/181098) about a week ago.</sub>

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555167/multiplicity-of-roots-of-a-fewnomial

Comment: @IgorRivin: I was the first to acknowledge this, see the small print at the end of my question.

Comment: Was too small for me to see :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by answering the question about polynomials with $N$ non-zero coefficients and a non-zero root of multiplicity $N-1$. Polynomials of the form $(x-a)^{N-1}$ are not the only such polynomials!

> **Theorem:** Let $m_{N}>m_{N-1}>\cdots >m_1\geq 0$ be $N$ given integers, and $a$ some non-zero complex number. There exists a unique monic polynomial
>   $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} c_ix^{m_i}$$
>   which has $a$ as a root of multiplicity $N-1$.
>
> **Proof:** The coefficients $c_i$ must satisfy $c_{N}=1$ and $N-1$ linear equations from $\frac{d^i}{dx^i}f (a)=0$ for $i=0,1,\dots,N-2$. If we define the matrix
>   $$A=\Big((j-1)!\binom{m_{N-i}}{j-1}a^{m_{N-i}}\Big)_{i,j=1}^{N-1}$$
>   our equations in the variables $v=(c_{N-1},\dots,c_1)$ can be writen as
>   $$Av^{T}=w$$
>   where $w=-a^{m_N}(1,m_N,2\binom{m_N}{2},\dots,(N-2)!\binom{m_N}{N-2})$. Finally notice that $A$ is invertible since it can easily be modified to a Vandermonde type matrix (like [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/268863/2384)).

Now, as far as your first question I have never seen these type of lemmas be called by a specific name, and they seem to be folklore. A recent article that talks about various generalizations is ["Root multiplicities and number of nonzero coefficients of a polynomial"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512239) which shows that these type of results have analogues in positive characteristic. You can find a couple of other references in there, as well.